# Unable to run a Python program with cron: cannot connect to X server

Tags: python, cron

I can't get my Python program (which runs in Terminal with no problem) to run through cron.

Here's the crontab command I use:

`38 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Cascades2/03_face_recognition.py >> /home/pi/Cascades2/cron.log 2>&1`

The error message that appears in the cron.log file is:

> : cannot connect to X server

What's the problem?

Comment: Apparently you are running (cron) under a user who has no visualization (X)

Comment: How could I fixe this?

Comment: Add the corresponding display in your cron (i.e  38  11 * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && your_script )

Comment: @tocode you saved me! Works great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Like tocode suggested, adding **export DISPLAY=:0.0 &&** to the script works perfectly.

`38 11 * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Cascades2/03_face_recognition.py >> /home/pi/Cascades2/cron.log 2>&1`